# Redirect based on time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

Is it possible to to have a javascript exit pop to redirect to a certain link based on a certain time of a video playing?

For example:

If the customer exits the page and the video was playing 0 - 0.5 seconds, redirect link 1.

If the customer exits the page and the video was playing 0.51 - 1 second, redirect link 2.

If so, can you provide resources or examples please?

EDIT

Basically I'm trying to create 2 different exit pops.  The video will auto play when page loads and depending on when the customer leaves the page will determine which exit pop to trigger.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: bind a time counter to the play button maybe...watch for mouseleave in addressbar direction or check if window looses focus...smth like that.

Comment: I am not sure even what to say here. it's so unclear. @abeCodes has the best solution imo. When you click play toggle a counter (in case they pause) that keeps running. But you have to take in account as well that when a person wants to restart the video, There are so many variables here you have to think out your proces. No I dont have examples, thats where you got Google for.

Comment: Not sure why I got -2 for my question.  Basically I'm trying to create 2 different exit pops.  The video will auto play when page loads and depending on when the customer leaves the page will determine which exit pop to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Have the button that triggers the video also trigger a timer. Example:

```
$('a.introVid').click(function () {
    autoPlayVideo('XGSy3_Czz8k', '420', '345');
});

function autoPlayVideo(vcode, width, height) {
    first = true;
    startTime();
    "use strict";
    $("#videoContainer").html('<iframe width="' + width + '" height="' + height + '" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + vcode + '?autoplay=1&loop=1&rel=0&wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen wmode="Opaque"></iframe>');
}

var h1,m1,s1 = 0;
var first = true;
function startTime() {
    var today=new Date();
    h=today.getHours();
    m=today.getMinutes();
    s=today.getSeconds();
    if (first)
    {
        h1 = h;
        m1 = m;
        s1 = s;
        first = false;
    }
    h -= h1;
    m -= m1;
    s -= s1;
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i<10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/byLa2cxf/